# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data in Angular

Tags: json, angular

I have an error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

with a validator json I realized that the error is in

```
 let json = JSON.stringify(user);
    let params = "json="+json; // here is the error in the "j" of json=
```

Error: Parse error on line 1:
json = {    "name": "p
^

```
json = {
    "name": "pedroeoeo",
    "surname": "oiuoiuoiu",
    "email": "iouoiu@hlkjlkj.com",
    "password": "lkjlkjlkj"
}
```

But I need to add to json = {"name":"kjlklk"... etc...

```
  register(user):Observable<any>
  {
    let json = JSON.stringify(user);
    console.log(json);
    let params = "json="+json;
    
    console.log(params);

    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this._http.post(this.url+'register', params, {headers:headers});
  }
```

the backend is made with laravel I tested it with postman and the backend it is ok but the problem is angular when I add to a json variable

````
json={"name":"pedroeoeo","surname":"oiuoiuoiu","email":"iouoiu@hlkjlkj.com","password":"lkjlkjlkj"
```}


I dont know how to fix it

I dont know what can I do to fix the issue
````

Answer (score 0):

Send it correctly.

```js
 register(user):Observable<any>
  {
    let body = { json: user };
    
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    return this._http.post(this.url+'register', body, {headers:headers});
  }
```

Comment: If I send the json using let body = {json: user); I got an 404 data sent invalid